# How to select between RC4 and AES when decrypting an encrypted PDF document

Tags: pdf

I'm writing code which parses and analyses PDFs and currently working on handling encryption within the documents.  I cannot understand from the specification how the choice between the 2 possible encryption methods is made.  Some details from the PDF specification...
The `V` field of the encrypt dictionary supports values including:

> 1 = "Algorithm 1: Encryption of data using the RC4 or AES algorithms" in
>   7.6.2, "General Encryption Algorithm," with an encryption key length of 40 bits; see below.
>
> 2 = (PDF 1.4) "Algorithm 1: Encryption of data
>   using the RC4 or AES algorithms"in 7.6.2, "General Encryption
>   Algorithm," but permitting encryption key lengths greater than 40
>   bits.

The `Length` field is defined as:

> (Optional; PDF 1.4; only if V is 2 or 3) The length of the encryption
>   key, in bits. The value shall be a multiple of 8, in the range 40 to
>   128. Default value: 40.

And part 7.6.2 General Encryption Algorithm lists the 2 possibilities:

> One of the following algorithms shall be used when encrypting data in
>   a PDF file:
>
> • A proprietary encryption algorithm known as RC4. [...]
>
> • The AES (Advanced Encryption Standard)
>   algorithm (beginning with PDF 1.6). ... and the length of the data when encrypted is rounded up to a multiple
>   of the block size, which is fixed to always be 16 bytes ...

I have a sample document with V = 2, length = 128 and it is PDF 1.6.  I had assumed that AES was used for documents in PDF 1.6 onwards, however decrypting it with AES fails (not least as the streams are not a multiple of 128 bits long).  Decrypting with RC4 succeeds.

My question is how can my code know to initialise for RC4 decryption at the start of processing the document?  I do not see anything in the Encrypt dictionary which specifies which method was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the specification is somewhat confusing here

> 2 = (PDF 1.4) "Algorithm 1: Encryption of data using the RC4 or AES
>   algorithms"in 7.6.2, "General Encryption Algorithm,"

is a **reference** to a section of the document that describes both RC4 and AES encryption, but `/V 4` is required to actually enable AES encryption.

> > 4 = (PDF 1.5) The security handler defines the use of encryption and decryption in the document, using the rules specified by the CF, StmF, and StrF entries.

So `/V 4`, or greater, is a prerequisite, from there you need to further consult the `/CF` `/StmF`, and `/StrF` entries.

A Encryption dictionary with basic `AES` encryption, might look like:

```
/Encrypt <<
  /V 4
  /R 4
  /StmF /StdCF
  /StrF /StdCF
  /CF <<
    /StdCF <<
      /CFM /AESV2
    >>
  >>
  % + other entries /O /U Length etc
>>
```

Comment: No, the sample document I am looking at has /V 2 and is encrypted with RC4.  /V 4 enables controlling encryption at the level of individual items in the document, whereas with /V1 or /V 2 all strings and streams use the same method.

Comment: This is the entire encrypt object:
`420 0 obj
<</Filter/Standard/Length 128/O...bytes.../P -1340/R 3/U...bytes.../V 2>>
endobj`
It is V=2 and there is no StmF or StrF.  If V=4, then yes, the other fields may specify the encryption method, but that's not the case in the document(s) in question.

Comment: The only method available with /V1 and /V2 is RC4

Comment: @Stuart *"No, the sample document I am looking at has..."* - if you have specific documents you're looking at in the context of a question, do share them to allow potential answerers not to waste time by answering in details you don't want at all.

Comment: @mkl - but I *did* put all the relevant fields of the encrypt dictionary in my original post.  Although I quoted the object raw in a comment here, it doesn't contain anything extra that's relevant

Comment: @dwarring, perhaps this is why we seem to be talking at cross purposes: in your answer where you put "but /V4 is required to actually enable **encryption**", did you mean to write "but /V 4 is required to actually enable **AES**" ?

Comment: @dwarring - that makes a lot more sense now.  I had read it literally and couldn't figure out why you were stating there was no encryption below /V4 !  And that's why I was arguing about it